# How to unflatten a multidimensional array (where original key access path is stored as a single key) in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, flatten

I'm using the following function to flatten a multidimensional array:

```
function flatten($array, $prefix = '') {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix . $key . '.');
        }
        else {
            $result[$prefix . $key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I'd like to create a matching function, `unflatten`, that will reverse the process(e.g create a child array if the key has a `.` in it). Any ideas?

Comment: instead of doing that is there a actual reason that this build/rebuild array functions are required? must be a better solution to a problem that you don't describe.

Comment: start with explode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php using the . as a delimiter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `parse_str` to get this done.just try below.

```
function flatten($array, $prefix = '') {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result = $result + flatten($value, $prefix . $key . '.');
        }
        else {
            $result[$prefix . $key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function unflatten($array,$prefix = '')
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(!empty($prefix))
        {
            $key = preg_replace('#^'.preg_quote($prefix).'#','',$key);
        }
        if(strpos($key,'.') !== false)
        {
            parse_str('result['.str_replace('.','][',$key)."]=".$value);
        }
        else $result[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}
$source    = array('a'=>'d','b',array('a'=>'c','d'));
$flattened = flatten($source,'__');
echo "<pre>";
echo "source array :<br/>";
print_r($source);
echo "flatten result:<br/>";
print_r($flattened);
echo "unflatten result:<br/>";
print_r(unflatten($flattened,'__'));
echo "<pre/>";
```

Outputs:

```
source array :
Array
(
    [a] => d
    [0] => b
    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => c
            [0] => d
        )

)
flatten result:
Array
(
    [__a] => d
    [__0] => b
    [__1.a] => c
    [__1.0] => d
)
unflatten result:
Array
(
    [a] => d
    [0] => b
    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => c
            [0] => d
        )

)
```

Comment: That is an excellent use of `parse_str`! I really wouldn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: problem with this solution -> it converts the values to strings, so in case you want to flatten/unflatten an array of integers, the result will different from the original array: unflatten(flatten([[1,2],[3,4])) === [["1","2"],["3","4"]] != original data

Comment: This is a very good bit of code, except that the syntax of `parse_str` changed from PHP 8.0. A second parameter to store the result is mandatory. Replacing the line with this code seems to do the trick: `parse_str('result['.str_replace('.','][',$key)."]=".$value,$result2);  $result = array_replace_recursive($result, $result2['result']);`. I'm using flatten/unflatten to save & retrieve json data into mysql.